# How can I hide MethodNotAllowedHttpException on laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

When we try to access url with an undefined method in laravel we get an exception of `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

If a route with `POST` request is called via `GET` request it will give us this exception.

What is the standard way of hiding this scary exception on laravel?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for any exception in **App\Exceptions\Handler@render**:

```
    if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }
```

And then render whatever view you want to tell the user what is happening.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo yep, for production you would definitely want to show some meaningful page to the user.

Answer (score 1):

In your config file set `Debug` to false in production. 
When debug is set to false it will display the default error page `Hmm.. Something went wrong...`.

You can make custom error pages, check the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors)

Comment: well it is already false ...such excepts have to be handled via handler

Answer (score 1):

One way is to disable Debug option, or you can use [Exception Handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors) to display an error page